# Count commits on one branch not on another

Tags: git

How would you count the number of commits on one (remote) branch that are not on another?

For example, let's say I have some feature branch, `origin/feature`, and I've been keeping it fairly up-to-date with `origin/master` by using `rebase --onto`. In other words, `origin/feature` is `origin/master`, with a few commits interlaced in between.

How would you count the number of commits that are on `origin/feature` and not on `origin/master`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`git cherry`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-cherry.html), good sir

```
git checkout master
git cherry feature | wc -l
```